«Я є людина» чи «Я є людиною»? Називний чи орудний?
Я стараюсь правильно підівчити українську мову, бо змалка живу в іншій країні, тому в українську школу ходила недовго (і тому перепрошую за помилки). І от у мене таке питання:
Як правильніше казати: «Я є людина» чи «Я є людиною»? Який відмінок використовувати, коли дієслово «бути» в теперішньому часі, називний чи орудний? Якщо опустити дієслово, то ніби ясно, називний: Я людина, Це стіл, Ця кімната — основна частина житла... Але от якщо не опускати? Все читаю про складені присудки, та ніяк не розберусь.

Коли ми перекладали CLRS, то мовред нам забороняв вживати є ким/чим. На жаль, не можу напевно згадати обгрунтування

Зазвичай тут виступаєʼ орудний, але називний тут допускаєʼся. Якщо опустити є, то все наопак.

Н. Л. Ковбаса : Форми називного та орудного відмінків у ролі іменної частини складеного присудка
[…] Із дієслівною зв’язкою «є» звичайно вживається орудний відмінок, а конструкції типу
«є + іменник в називному відмінку» трапляються рідко. Наприклад: «Чай готовий, —
зауважив Професор, — книжка є моя свята власність» (Яновський); «Будинки дивної краси
ростуть на пустирях окраїн... щаслива, земле, ти єси, що більшовик є твій хазяїн»
(Рильський); «Знав я друзів своїх, що не мали хвальби, а чи зради, бо хвальба — то є тлінь, а від зради немає поради» (Малишко). Пор.: «На жаль, поки що папір у багатьох наших
установах є головним засобом» (Збанацький).
У реченнях з опущеною зв’язкою «є» звичайно вживається називний відмінок. Наприклад: «І знаю, що ти — комунізму дорога, що ти — це життя, боротьба, перемога» (Первомайський); «Так стій за владу Рад в своїй напрузі звичній, бо ти її солдат і охоронець вічний» (Первомайський).
Орудний відмінок іменника в цих випадках — нечасте явище, пояснюється він
найчастіше особливою будовою тавтологічних зворотів. Наприклад: «Критика критикою, а
тон тоном» (Збанацький). […]

В тій ж статтї, якщо цїкаво, розглянуто гинші випадки: був, будь і бути.

Споріднене запитання, де йдеться про складені іменникові присудки, що складаються з прикметника:

Як узгодити присудок з підметом? Він буде вправнИМ, чи вправнИЙ?

Серед інших посилань, там наведена думка Антоненка-Давидовича стосовно конструкцій виду «іменник {є} іменник», яка пропонує використовувати:

називний відмінок, якщо йдеться про постійно притаманну властивість (стативна предикація);
орудний відмінок, коли властивість мала місце у минулому, майбутньому, або тимчасова (мінлива предикація).

Чтиво по темі:

Як позбутися неоднозначності при використанні перехідного відмінку?
Conventions for the omission of verb `Є`
також я колись написав англомовну статтю на Linguistics.SE про це саме явище у польській мові: Instrumental - nominative inversion in Polish


Дякую, за вартісне посилання, але гадаю, що ви помилились у своєму тлумаченні написаного А-Д. Він пише про варіанти саме без є, тоді як запитання саме про з є. Про варіант з є він згадує лише цитуючи Потебню, де вказується, що це полонизм.

@Yola ого, і це настільки погана відповідь, що навіть заслуговує мінусу? Роблю висновки, дякую.

Ця відповідь хоч і дуже корисна ресурсами, до яких покликається, все ж дуже погана, бо вводить в оману читача. Допоки я не перейшов за посиланням на власне текст А-Д, я думав, що він говорить про структуру з є також. Я із задоволенням приберу мінус, якщо ви приберете {є} і після списку додасте, своє обгрунтування чому сказане А-Д стосується і варіанту з є, але має бути чітко видно, що це саме ваше обгрунтування, а не А-Д.

@Yola ви помиляєтеся і своєю помилкою, дійсно, вводите в оману інших читачів. Дилема не між «присудки з "є"» проти «присудки без "є"». Тому що тире є повноцінною заміною дієслова. Слово "{є}" недаремно написано у фігурних дужках як placeholder для «є, був, була, буде, будеш, будемо, або просто тире».

@Yola Думаю, ваша помилка спричинена нерозумінням, що протиставлення відбувається між «складені присудки на основі прикметника» проти  «складені присудки на основі іменника». У пов'язаному запитанні йдеться про прикметникові, а тут — про іменникові. Знайдіть трохи часу і прочитайте запитання, відповідь і тексти за посиланнями. Там цікаво, запевняю. Трошки забагато академічної термінології, але може бути цікаво навіть для не фахівців.
